# Google apps script giving different results coping file

Tags: google-drive-api

I keep getting different results from this code I only have one file in the source at any given time but I get a random number of copies in the destination folder? sometimes I get just the one sometimes I get 5

```
function myFunction(source_folder, dest_folder) {
  source_folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder()
  dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID")

  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('FileName');
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName());
    dest_folder.addFile(file);
    source_folder.removeFile(file);
  }
}
```

Comment: So, `DriveApp.getFilesByName('FileName')` returns more than 1 file? What are the names of the files it returns?

Comment: the same name so if the file is called test i get 1, 5, 3, 6 files called test in the destination folder

Comment: javascript = asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

The code is getting all files in the user's Drive that have the given name. You say:

> I only have one file in the source at any given time

so you should be getting just the files in source_folder. To fix, change this line:

```
var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('FileName');
```

to this:

```
var files = source_folder.getFilesByName('FileName');
```

Comment: That fixed it Thank you :)